# Storing tens of millions of arrays efficiently

Tags: arrays, parse-platform

I would like to allow my users to store arrays of integers in the Parse.com cloud permanently or semi-permanently. There are tens of thousands of users. Each user will want to store hundreds of arrays. Each array will contain hundreds of integers. A user should be able to query the database with an integer key to retrieve one of their arrays.

I, the owner, should be able to query the database and download the whole data set over HTTP.

There will be tens of millions of arrays stored, which I believe will require on the order of 50-500 GB of storage in the Parse cloud.

Is this idea technically viable and if so: what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Can you get a free Parse account to test this on a smaller scale? Or maybe contact their sales department and ask them this question?

Comment: You want to download 50-500 GB over HTTP?

Comment: With that amount of data, use `rsync` or similar if you can, and if the data doesn't churn significantly.

Comment: Well, actually, it is probably possible to compress it to about 5-50 GB and store it as tens of millions of relatively short strings instead of arrays.